# Compare values from group_concat in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to compare values from group_concat in mysql. My query for this moment is:

```
SELECT it.Nr_Inwentarzowy,
       GROUP_CONCAT(it.Nazwa),
       GROUP_CONCAT(it.U_ytkownik),
       GROUP_CONCAT(it.Pok_j),
       COUNT(*),
       GROUP_CONCAT(z.Nr_inwentarzowy),
       z.Nazwa_maj_tku
FROM intaktualny AS it
JOIN zestawycsv AS z
WHERE it.Nr_Inwentarzowy = z.Nr_inwentarzowy
GROUP BY (it.Nr_Inwentarzowy)
```

which return me http://prntscr.com/fbup3i.

**I need** to compare values from group concat on `GROUP_CONCAT(it.u_ytkownik), GROUP_CONCAT(it.pok_j)`, and if first and second values are the same, then add a column, where I need to put "OK". How to do it?

Comment: Your question is unclear... Can you example input and desired output?

Comment: Inputs are: code numbers, names of computer parts, users and rooms. My problem is shown here: http://prntscr.com/fbuvi0

Comment: if they are not equal? would you like to put any value? @MarcinGąsiorek

Comment: I think, i could put there "not ok"

Comment: I had code numbers, which are assigned to different parts. That parts are assigned to user. Users are assigned to rooms. When users and rooms in group_concat are the same, i need to add column "approved" and put there "ok". Else i need to add column "not approved" and put there "not ok". This is shown in link above.

Comment: @MarcinGąsiorek check my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just extract the first two values from within the `GROUP_CONCAT` using `SUBSTRING_INDEX` and check whether they are equal

Something like

```
SELECT it.Nr_Inwentarzowy,
       GROUP_CONCAT(it.Nazwa),
       GROUP_CONCAT(it.U_ytkownik),
       GROUP_CONCAT(it.Pok_j),
       COUNT(*),
       GROUP_CONCAT(z.Nr_inwentarzowy),
       IF(
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(it.U_ytkownik), ',', 1) = 
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(it.U_ytkownik), ',', 2),  ',', -1), 
       'OK', 'NOT OK')
       z.Nazwa_maj_tku
FROM intaktualny AS it
JOIN zestawycsv AS z
WHERE it.Nr_Inwentarzowy = z.Nr_inwentarzowy
GROUP BY (it.Nr_Inwentarzowy)
```

** Note : this code will print "OK" if there are less then 2 values... you didn't write what to do in this case...

Comment: What is e.FName ?

Comment: Also, my code only checks this on one column, should be easy enough to do on both...

Comment: Okay, it works. When there are less than 2 values, then print "not ok". Can you @YossiVainshtein? And if there are 3 values, then put "not ok" too

Comment: Ok, got it ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
 select if(first=second,"ok", "not okay") as status,* from (
 SELECT it.Nr_Inwentarzowy,
   GROUP_CONCAT(it.Nazwa),
   GROUP_CONCAT(it.U_ytkownik) as first,
   GROUP_CONCAT(it.Pok_j) as second,
   COUNT(*),
   GROUP_CONCAT(z.Nr_inwentarzowy),
   z.Nazwa_maj_tku
FROM intaktualny AS it
JOIN zestawycsv AS z
WHERE it.Nr_Inwentarzowy = z.Nr_inwentarzowy
GROUP BY (it.Nr_Inwentarzowy)
) as alias
```

if `first equals second` add the `OK` in status column else add `not ok`.

Comment: @MarcinGąsiorek yes, that was a type. Check now,

Comment: Something is wrong in your syntax next to '* from ( - i'm using phpmyadmin